# how to link to a specific div from an image

Tags: html, css, anchor

i am currently working on a school project. 
[please click HERE to see my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT2p3.jpg)

i have 3 bottle images that i like to be clickable so that if i click a bottle, it will redirect me to a div.

here's what my html looks like:

```css
.zero {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #f8f5f2;
  color: 000b29;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.secOne {
  background-image: url("../img/hero/premium.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionOne {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #000B29;
  color: #d70026;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.secTwo {
  background-image: url("../img/hero/black.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionTwo {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #D70026;
  color: #f8f5f2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.secThree {
  background-image: url("../img/hero/goldhero.jpg");
}

.sub_sectionThree {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #edb83d;
  color: #d70026;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <video id="bgvid" autoplay loop poster="img/Snapshot/Beach-Ball.jpg" alt="people playing soccer at the beach">
       <source src="img/Mp4/Beach-Ball.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
       <source src="img/Ogv/Beach-Ball.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
       <source src="img/Webm/Beach-Ball.webm" type="video/webm" />
   </video>
  <!-- bottle navigation -->
  <div class="bottle">
    <h1>Beast Mode On</h1>
    <div class="bottle-nav">
      <img src="img/bottles/125_bluelightningbottle.png" alt="Oztonic Premium Energy Drink Bottle">
      <img src="img/bottles/125_redlightningbottle.png" alt="OzTonic Black Energy Drink Bottle">
      <img src="img/bottles/125_yellowlightningbottle.png" alt="OzTonic Gold Energy Drink Bottle">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- sections -->
  <div class="zero">
    <h2>Which Beast Are You?</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section secOne"></div>
  <div class="sub_sectionOne">
    <h2>I'm a Premium Beast</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section secTwo"></div>
  <div class="sub_sectionTwo">
    <h2>I'm a Black Beast</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="section secThree"></div>
  <div class="sub_sectionThree">
    <h2>I'm a Gold Beast</h2>
  </div>
```

so i like to get my 125_bluelightningbottle.png to redirect me to 
div class="section secOne. my 125_redlightningbottle.png to redirect me to
div class="section secTwo. and my 125_yellowlightningbottle.png to redirect me to div class="section secThree.

those divs with class are styled by these (please see css codes below) and as you can see, my images are set as a background-img: url("..img/hero/black.jpg'); and so on...

however this is what i tried and i have a problem doing this:
if i use the  and wrap the bottle.png with it and put
 and wrap my div class="section secOne" all my background-img disappears.

your help is appreciated in advance

Comment: Just add an ID for each div that you want to redirect and in your image link set it like : href="#divID"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to a div when clicking on your image, you could wrap each image in a  tag with an anchor and add an id on the target element.

```
    <a href="#secOne">
        <img src="img/bottles/125_bluelightningbottle.png" alt="Oztonic Premium Energy Drink Bottle">
    </a>
    <div class="section secOne" id="secOne">Your Div</span>
```

Then, if you click on `seOne` anchor you will go to the `#seOne` element.

[Here's an explanation](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="section">
<video id="bgvid" autoplay loop poster="img/Snapshot/Beach-Ball.jpg" alt="people playing soccer at the beach">
    <source src="img/Mp4/Beach-Ball.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="img/Ogv/Beach-Ball.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
    <source src="img/Webm/Beach-Ball.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
<!-- bottle navigation -->        
<div class="bottle">
    <h1>Beast Mode On</h1>
    <div class="bottle-nav">
        <a href="#secOne"><img src="img/bottles/125_bluelightningbottle.png" alt="Oztonic Premium Energy Drink Bottle"></a>
        <a href="#secTwo"><img src="img/bottles/125_redlightningbottle.png" alt="OzTonic Black Energy Drink Bottle"></a>
        <a href="#secThree"><img src="img/bottles/125_yellowlightningbottle.png" alt="OzTonic Gold Energy Drink Bottle"></a>
    </div>    
</div>
<!-- sections -->
<div class="zero">
    <h2>Which Beast Are You?</h2>    
</div>   
<div class="section secOne" id="secOne"></div>
<div class="sub_sectionOne">
    <h2>I'm a Premium Beast</h2>
</div>  
<div class="section secTwo" id="secTwo"></div>
<div class="sub_sectionTwo">
    <h2>I'm a Black Beast</h2>
</div>
<div class="section secThree" id="secThree"></div>
<div class="sub_sectionThree">
    <h2>I'm a Gold Beast</h2>
</div>
```

Replace your html code by above html code.